How would you go about cloning Pump.fun smart contracts?
I want to make a pump.fun clone, how would I go about rewriting the smart contracts that pump.fun uses, ie the token minting, bonding curve, adding and removing liquidity etc. How would I go about doing this and where can I look to get started?

I'd start with getting some context. Here's a tutorial on it.
https://docs.chainstack.com/docs/solana-creating-a-pumpfun-bot
It's about creating a bot for pumpfun, but will give an idea how to work with its contracts.
P.S. I'm a Developer Advocate at Chainstack.

I've published basic pumpfun smart contract/frontend/backend code in github.
If you are familiar to it, it wouldn't take difficult to launch your project based on it.
Here's the github link.
https://github.com/m8s-lab/pump-fun-smart-contract
https://github.com/m8s-lab/pump-fun-frontend
https://github.com/m8s-lab/pump-fun-backend
